# Kotlin and String.contains() not working as I thought

Tags: string, kotlin, substring, contains

I thought I knew how string.contains() worked in Kotlin and Java, but apparently I don't.

I'vet got a small piece of code that takes a list of file names, and puts them in another list if the do not contain certain words.

```
for (i in 0..filliste.size-1) {
    if (!filliste[i].contains("utenfastbopel") || !filliste.contains("sperret") ||
        !filliste.contains("reservert")){
            var a = filliste[i]
            tempFnrliste += filliste[i].split("_")[0]
    }
}
```

However, this does not exclude a file which contains the phrase "sperretstrengtreservert", even though both "reservert" and "sperret" is in the "not contains".

How come? I thought .contains found every occurence of a substring?

But if you look at the debug run, a file containing two of the phrases that are to be ignored, is indeed not ignored:

[image]

UPDATE:

To be clear, I'm looking for any of the file names to contain one OR more of the strings. So the logical OR/|| is correct.

However, I missed some indices. But adding them changed nothing. See the updated code below:

[image]

As far as I can see, the code now clearly says IF THE STRING DOES NOT CONTAIN THIS, THIS OR THIS SUBSTRING... But still, a string containing two of the substrings gets a match.

Strangely, if I only use ONE substring in the "not-contains" - for instance "reservert", the code does indeed skip all strings not containing that. But when I use the || operator for several substrings, things gets messed up.

Comment: didn't you forget 2 `[i]` after the second and third `!filliste` ?

Comment: You're right. Strangely though, fixing that did nothing.

Comment: @Hfrav What do you want? In question you say you want the string to contain one or more of the substring but then you say you want a string that does not contain that substring?

Comment: @TheLibrarian Read the question. It says "and puts them in another list if the do not contain certain words#. What's unclear?

Comment: "I'm looking for any of the file names to contain one OR more of the strings. "

Comment: Well, I DO use !, so - a typo, ok?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`"sperretstrengtreservert"` does not contain `utenfastbopel`.

You are using `||` aka `OR`. Your first condition is true.

If **any** of these is true, it will go to the body of the condition.

```
!filliste[i].contains("utenfastbopel") ||
!filliste.contains("sperret") ||
!filliste.contains("reservert")
```

Also as said you are not accessing the same object in the follow-up conditions although it wouldn't change the result as is.

You need to change it from "***at least one** of these conditions must be true*" to "***all** of these conditions must be true*" `&&` aka `AND`.

```
for (i in 0..filliste.size-1) {
    val f = filliste[i]
    if (!f.contains("utenfastbopel") && !f.contains("sperret") && !f.contains("reservert")) {
        tempFnrliste += f.split("_")[0]
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hfrav Note that NOT(A OR B) is not the same as NOT(A) OR NOT(B). (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).)

Comment: @gidds Hm, yeah. I know, and see. How to do it in kotlin/java code, though?

Comment: @Hfrav Simply note that `!f.contains("utenfastbopel") && !f.contains("sperret") && …` means the same as `!(f.contains("utenfastbopel") || f.contains("sperret") || …)`. And see whether perhaps this answer does what you want after all…?

Comment: You're right, of course. Me messing with OR and AND here. Thanks :-)